# Limiting posts_join, where, etc to a specific WP_Query object?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I hope this makes any type of sense.  I want to be able to add clauses to a specific query object without effecting the main loop on a page, for example for content in a side bar or footer.  Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly to you want to acchieve? Maybe there's an easier way with normal query args?

Comment: I have two post types, one that will be sorted by a parent post title, a taxonomy and a meta vale and one by a parent post title, a taxonomy and two separate meta values.  I didn't think WP was robust enough via the query args, so I'm using the post_clauses hook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most reliable way is to define your own query var and then check it:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
  ...
  'context' => 'my_query'
) );
```

Then, from your callback:

```
function alter_post_clauses( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
  if ( 'my_query' == $wp_query->get( 'context' ) ) {
    // do stuff
  }

  return $clauses;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'alter_post_clauses', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: hmm, that works.  Thanks, scribu.  Deceptively simple coding wins again.

Answer (score 0):

6 Years later, I have to confirm that this is the easiest and rock-proof way of handling conditionals in posts_* filters.